# Delete Request Records Before Sending a New GET Request Djando

Tags: javascript, html, django, api

I am building a web app using Django. I am not that familiar with javascript/html since it is not my domain of specialty.

What I am doing is searching for a name that will be looked up in the api and it will return it with other information.

I'll post the codes which I think is realted to my issue. If you need anything more, I can provide it.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import  render
from .models import customer
import requests

def get_customer(request):
    all_customers = {}
    if 'name' in request.GET:
        name = request.GET['name']
        url = 'https://retoolapi.dev/aSIZJV/customer__data?FirstName=%s'%name

        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        customers = data

        for i in customers:
            customer_data = customer(
                uid = i['id'],
                f_name = i['FirstName'],
                m_name = i['MiddleName'],
                l_name = i['LastName'],
                phone = i['Phone'],
                email = i['Email'],
                DOB=i['DateOfBirth'],
                EID=i['EmiratesID']

            )
            customer_data.save()
            all_customers = customer.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    return render (request, 'customer.html', { "all_customers": all_customers} )
```

**customer.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "text-center container">
      <br>
      <h2 class = "text-center">Search for the desired customer</h2>
      <br>
      <form method="GET">
        <input type='button' value='Remove Table Body' onclick='removeTableBody()'/>
          
<!--          I am trying to remove the table body using the line above, but it is not working-->
          
          
        <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder="Search..." class = "text-center"> 
        <button type = "submit" class = "btn-danger btn-sm">SEARCH CUSTOMER</button>
      </form>

    </div>
    <br><br>


    <div class="container">
    <h1>Customer Table</h1>

    <div id="toolbar">
            <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Export Basic</option>
                    <option value="all">Export All</option>
                    <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
            </select>
    </div>

    <table id="table"
                 data-toggle="table"
                 data-search="true"
                 data-filter-control="true"
                 data-show-export="true"
                 data-click-to-select="true"
                 data-toolbar="#toolbar">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                <th data-field="ID">ID</th>
                <th data-field="FirstName" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">First Name</th>
                <th data-field="MiddleName" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Middle Name</th>
                <th data-field="LastName" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Last Name</th>
                <th data-field="Phone" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Phone</th>
                <th data-field="Email" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Email</th>
                <th data-field="DateOfBirth" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Date Of Birth</th>
                <th data-field="EmiratesID" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">EmiratesID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for customer in all_customers %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>{{customer.uid}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.f_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.m_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.l_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.DOB}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.EID}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
<!-- partial -->
```

**static/website/dist/script.js**

```
var $table = $('#table');
    $(function () {
        $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
            $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                exportDataType: $(this).val()
            });
        });
    })

        var trBoldBlue = $("table");

    $(trBoldBlue).on("click", "tr", function (){
            $(this).toggleClass("bold-blue");
    });


var $table_empty = $('#table');
    $(function removeTableBody() {
        $('#table tbody').empty();
    })
// I wrote the line above to empty the table
```

When I press the button to empty the rows in the table, I see this on the terminal:

```
[15/Dec/2021 15:34:05] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2283
[15/Dec/2021 15:34:05] "GET /script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2283
```

This a view of how the table looks:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3QIJ.png)

I want to get new responses everytime I send a GET request.

Comment: I'm concerned by the 404 for your script.js and style.css. Maybe you've misconfigured your static files. Check your STATIC_ROOT setting in your settings file and maybe review this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/ to make sure you have everything set up correctly. My guess is your STATIC_ROOT is just ~/static and not ~/static/web/dist so it's just not finding anything. Maybe chuck a console.log into your script.js to confirm it's being loaded.

Comment: @Lachlan Yes, you are correct. The STATIC_ROOT is only /static. I'll change it to the full path as you've suggested.

Comment: posted comment as an answer for those sweet sweet points :)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that your .css and your .js are reporting 404 not found, I'm going to assume that it's an issue with your static root. I think by default the STATIC_ROOT in your settings file will be /static, but your js is apparently at /static/web/dist, so you should either update your STATIC_ROOT to /static/web/dist or specify the path from /static in your base.html when you're loading the files.

(Edit)
Also. Your View is requesting data from another website and saving all the data it receives as new model instances. You're getting duplicates on your page because you have duplicates in your database, not because of the javascript.

Your javascript is set up to reload the page every time you hit Search Customer, so, the javascript failing to clear the table is definitely irrelevant to your duplicate problem.

Lastly, your removeTableBody function is inside $( ) which means the function only exists inside the scope of those brackets. So if you click your clear table button, I'm sure it would post to your console that the removeTableBody function doesn't exist. Remove the $( ).

Comment: So I solved 404 error by adjusting the static path in the customer.html file. But the main problem of not being able to pass GET requests without storing the response in the HTML session is not working. I keep on aggregating responses every time I initiate a GET request.

Comment: check the edit :)